Unable to run 'sudo mvn' in WSL
When trying to run sudo with mvn e.g. 'sudo mvn spring-boot:run', in WSL (Ubuntu 24), I get the following error: 'sudo: mvn: command not found'.
Obviously, maven is installed and runs perfectly without sudo. Also, running sudo with other commands works fine as well e.g. sudo apt-get update etc.
Just to preclude any questions why I am trying to run 'sudo mvn spring-boot:run' is that when I ran it without sudo, my SpringBoot app crashes with 'java.net.BindException: Permission denied', probably on port 80, although the error stacktrace doesn't say so  (in application.preperties, server.port=80, and the port is not in use i.e. sudo lsof -i:80 shows nothing).
The aforementioned Permission denied error happens on both my WSL and my AWS EC2 instance (which also uses Ubuntu 24), but the way I overcome it on EC2 is by using sudo, but I can't do the same on WSL.
Would be grateful for any suggestions.

Why do you want to run mvn under sudo?

@tripleee, from my OP:
The error (i.e.BindException: Permission denied) happens on both my WSL and my AWS EC2 instance (which also uses Ubuntu 24), but the way I overcome it on EC2 is by using sudo, but I can't do the same on WSL.

Can you post the result of type mvn and sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH' ?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78457581/874188 has a simple solution for a similar problem. (It needs to be said that many of the other answers there are atrociously bad.)

@tripleee, as you alluded to, WSL was using maven installed on windows, so I tried to add maven dir to PATH as in SO post you suggested. However, by some reason, new path only persist in "Windows" portion of it (where it was already set), but not Linux portion:
$ sudo bash -c 'export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/system/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin' $ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH' $ /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin $ export PATH=$PATH:/mnt/c/system/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin $ echo $PATH ...:/mnt/c/system/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin
Setting PATH in bashrc result in the same

@Philippe
$ type mvn $ mvn is /mnt/c/system/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin/mvn $ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH' $ /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
please also see my answer to tripleee

Can you try sudo -E mvn spring-boot:run ?

@Philippe, unfortunately, did't help i.e. still getting: sudo: mvn: command not found

If you can't or don't want to update the PATH, rpecify the full path to mvn; sudo /mnt/c/system/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin/mvn spring-boot:run

Thank you, that worked. I would prefer to use Philippe's solution though

If you have in /etc/sudoers :
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

Try to add maven directory :
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/mnt/c/system/apache-maven-3.9.6/bin"

